# Android: How to add custom field/action to contact detail

Tags: android, contacts

I would add custom action into system contact detail of Android like Viber (see attached screenshot) and other messaging apps do. 
When user clicks on such custom action, my app will handle. Any help?

[image: Contact detail with Viber's action]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it is as easy as it sounds. From what I see you need to  create a new Account on the device to achieve something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17164257/).